# JMeter LDAP tests using GSSAPI/kerberos credentials

Tags: jmeter, openldap, gssapi

I would like to use JMeter to run some load testing against our OpenLDAP service authenticating using GSSAPI (i.e., Kerberos). How do I get JMeter to use a keytab with Kerberos credentials to do this? (Note: I tried following the directions here but they did not work for me: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/141035/jmeter-kerberos-setup-for-hive-load-testing.html)

UPDATE

The command I use to start JMeter is

```
java.exe -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms1g -Xmx1g 
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom
-Duser.language="en" -Duser.region="EN"
-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext 
-jar "D:\JMeter\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar"  
-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true 
-Djava.security.krb5.conf="D:\JMeter\bin\krb5.conf"
-Djava.security.auth.login.config="D:\JMeter\bin\jaas.conf"
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false
```

The contents of `D:\JMeter\bin\jaas.conf`:

```
JMeter {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=true
    useTicketCache=false
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="D:\JMeter\bin\ldap.keytab"
    principal="service/testing-prod@example.com"
    debug=true;
};
```

I have a single LDAP Request sampler. For that sampler I entered the LDAP server, port, and search base and filter. I run the test which "succeeds" but no information comes back.

I see **no** log messages in `jmeter.log` concerning the success or failure of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your `didn't work` statement tells nothing to us. With regards to the referenced guide - it is fine for HortonWorks Docs, however it might be not applicable for your application setup as Kerberos has many faces, to wit:

1. Your [REALM](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/admin/realm_config.html) will be different
2. Your [SPN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/autz_auth_stuff/2011/04/28/what-is-a-spn-and-why-should-you-care/) will be different (it may or may not be present)
3. Your keytab configuration will be different (again, Kerberos may or may not use keytabs for authentication)
4. Your [KDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/key-distribution-center) will be different
5. Your keytab generation algorithms may be different

So I would recommend the following:

1. Reach out to your network administrators / developers / devops / whoever can have the knowledge about your Kerberos setup and collect as much information as you can
2. [Enable debug logging for JMeter HTTP Authorization Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
   ```
3. Enable debug logging for Java Kerberos implementation by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

   ```
   sun.security.krb5.debug=true
   ```
4. Restart JMeter to pick up the changes
5. Re-run your test and look for underlying error cause in *jmeter.log* file and in [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))
6. Fix the issue
7. Repeat step 5 until you're happy with the result

There are hundreds of different reasons, it might be the case your setup is 100% fine, however your login doesn't succeed because you have different time on KDC and your JMeter machine and it needs syncing.

Comment: Updated my original post with more information on what I have set up and what I am seeing.